# How to find date difference from Date in string format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two dates as From and To in String format as `1/11/2015` and `15/11/2015`. What are the ways to find the difference in days between two dates. Remember the dates are in String format not in JavaScript Date format.

Comment: you can convert them into Date Object and then compute the diff

Comment: Look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Comment: The [`Date(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor can take a string as an argument and covert it into a date.

Comment: new Date('15/11/2015') will give you invalid date. You have to use new Date('11/15/2015').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert them to dates using

```
function convertToDate(str)
{
   var dateArr = str.split("/");
   return new Date(dateArr[2], dateArr[1], dateArr[0])
}
var date1 = convertToDate("1/11/2015");
var date2 = convertToDate("15/11/2015");
var diffInDays = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())/ (1000*60*60*24);

alert( Math.ceil( Math.abs( diffInDays ) ) );
```

`getTime` returns number of milliseconds since 1970, so you need to convert them to days by dividing it with `24 * 60 *60 * 1000` ()

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple in JS.

1. Convert the Strings into Unix Timestamps
2. Get the difference
3. Convert the difference into days

i.e. in JS

```
//Since your dates are in DD/MM/YY we have to modify it a bit
var d1 = '1/11/2015'.split('/')
var d2 = '15/11/2015'.split('/')

//This is our converted format that is MM/DD/YY
var normd1 = [d1[1],d1[0],d1[2]].join('/')
var normd2 = [d2[1],d2[0],d2[2]].join('/')

//Get the difference in ms and use the absolute value incase you switched the days
var diff = Math.abs(Date.parse(norm1) - Date.parse(normd2))

//convert the difference to days
var days = diff/(1000*60*60*24 )
```

`Date.parse`  converts a date string into a millisecond UNIX timestamp, i.e. number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to achieve your desired result.

```
var fromDt = new Date("11/1/2015"), toDt = new Date("11/15/2015");
var moment = require('moment');
```

Convert into millisecond.

```
var fromDate = moment(fromDt).format('X') * 60000;
var toDate = moment(toDt).format('X') * 60000;
```

Get the difference.

```
var diffMs = toDate - fromDate;
```

Now you can use the desired format you want.

> NOTE :- diffMs will give you difference in milliseconds. You can convert it to know the difference.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Why use a library when it's already supported and simpler in native JavaScript?

Comment: If you are working with date calculation frequently, it is easier to do it through moment.js. I am using it to do this kind of calcuations.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the function for mmddyy format of date

```
function dateDiff(d1,d2){
    var date1 = new Date(d1)
    var date2 = new Date(d2);
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    return(diffDays);
}
```

The Date function is capable of handling strings. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date